# How to compare 2 arrays and merge them / override and extract only relevant data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following data:

**arrayA**

```
 [3 , 4]
```

**arrayB**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    user: {
      id: 1,
      username: 'John'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    user: {
      id: 3,
      username: 'Mary'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    user: {
      id: 4,
      username: 'Dog'
    }
  }
]
```

I wish to get the resulting array

```
['Mary' , 'Dog']
```

Answer (score 2):

The reducer function could be used here. It would iterate over each element of the array, resulting in a single output array, which would satisfy the required condition.
With `reduce()` method, this could be done in a single array iteration.

Condition: The id to be checked in the array of Ids.

```
const ids = [3 , 4]
const arr = [{id:1, user: {id:1 , username:'John'} },
{id:3, user: {id:3 , username:'Mary'} },
{id:4, user: {id:4 , username:'Dog'} }]

const val = arr.reduce((acc, currentVal) => {
    const {id, user: { username } = {} } = currentVal
    if (ids.indexOf(id) > -1) {
        acc.push(username)
    }
    return acc
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse through `arrayB` and see if the `id` is in `arrayA`, if so, get the username value.

See below:

```js
const arrayA = [3, 4]
const arrayB = [{
    id: 1,
    user: {
      id: 1,
      username: 'John'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    user: {
      id: 3,
      username: 'Mary'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    user: {
      id: 4,
      username: 'Dog'
    }
  }
]

// Look through the array to see if the id is included in arrayA
// If so get the username, because the map will return false if not in
// arrayA, a simple Boolean filter gets rid of any false in the resulting array 

const usernames = arrayB.map(i => arrayA.includes(i.id) && i.user.username).filter(Boolean);

console.log(usernames)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get username based on `arrayA`,

- First [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/filter) `arrayB` based on element present in `arrayA`
- use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/map) to get value of all `usernames` from `user` object

```js
var arrA = [3 , 4]


var arrB = [{id: 1, user: { id: 1, username: 'John'}},
            {id: 3, user: { id: 3, username: 'Mary'}}, 
            {id: 4, user: { id: 4, username: 'Dog' }}]

var result = arrB.filter(x => arrA.includes(x.id))  //Filter by id
                 .map(y => y.user.username) //Select user.username
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter` for the objects matching `id` and then `map` to the username

```js
var arr1 = [3 , 4];
var arr2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    user: {
      id: 1,
      username: 'John'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    user: {
      id: 3,
      username: 'Mary'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    user: {
      id: 4,
      username: 'Dog'
    }
  }
];
var names = arr2.filter(x => arr1.includes(x.id))
                .map(y => y.user.username);
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that loops through the arrays and pushes the relevant value to a new array whenever arrays' relevant elements (arrayA - element, arrayB - element's id) match.

```
extract(arrayA, arrayB) => {
    let resultArr=[];

    for (let i=0; i<arrayA.length; i++) {
        for (let j=0; j<arrayB.length; j++) {
            if (arrayB[j].id===(arrayA[i]))
                resultArr.push(arrayB[j].user.username);
        }
    }

    return resultArr;
}
```

For sure it's not the most elegant way (two loops are not efficient), you could play with map() and filter() functions to acheive efficiency. That's just the simplest way, I think.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would help to improve the quality of your answer. Remember that you are also answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer reduce, since you can do everything in 1 loop. and result is much readable.

```js
const arrayA = [3, 4];
const arrayB = [{
    id: 1,
    user: {
      id: 1,
      username: 'John'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    user: {
      id: 3,
      username: 'Mary'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    user: {
      id: 4,
      username: 'Dog'
    }
  }
];

const reducer = (acc, x) => arrayA.includes(x.id) ? [...acc, x.user.username] : acc;

const result = arrayB.reduce(reducer, []);

console.log({result});
```